# The value of local integer variables is not written correctly using TextWriter

Tags: c#, textwriter

So the problem is this I declare the variables and open the stream at the begining of the method:

```
    int i = 0;
    int FailedToCopyImages = 0;
    int NumberOfCopiedImages = 0;
    int PreviouslyCopiedImages = 0;
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(pathToFile, true);
```

Then I do some stuff in `try-catch-finally` block and in the `finally part I have :

```
finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Console.WriteLine(NumberOfCopiedImages);
                Console.WriteLine(PreviouslyCopiedImages);
                Console.WriteLine(FailedToCopyImages);
                tw.WriteLine(" ");
                tw.WriteLine("All images: " + i +
                    " | Successfully copied: " + NumberOfCopiedImages +
                    " | Previously copied: " + PreviouslyCopiedImages +
                    " | Failed To Copy: " + FailedToCopyImages);
                tw.WriteLine("--------------End Of Material Images-------------");
```

I do this in four methods and I get the right results there. Here in the Console I see that the variables holds the correct value but in the txt file I get zeroes (0).

Comment: Something else must be going on. Try setting a breakpoint at the line `tw.WriteLine("All images: "...` and see what the values of the local variables are at that point.

Comment: I did - the values are what they should be (non zero)

Comment: Is it possible the TextWrite to save some cache. I deleted `tw.WriteLine("All images: " + i +..` but I still get it in my txt file.

Comment: It won't write anything in a file if you don't tell it to. The cache can only delay writing to a file. Rename/delete the file and run again?

Comment: Just did it, good idea but still I get text that I've deleted and clean-rebuild my solution... strange.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. I was using `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments  + "\\PictureStat.txt)` for path and it seems this holds some cache afterall or whatever. But I changed the path and it works OK. As it was before I set it to MyDocuments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you need to call `tw.Flush()` and `tw.Close()` (or just wrap `new StreamWriter(..)` in `using (...)` statement) before seeing results in file.

Even if it seems to start working with other file path (as you commented) - there's no magic (at least in programming) - and it will fail someday without proper `Flush` / `Dispose`.